# Point plotting with a line graph

Tags: mathematics, javascript, geometry, phaser

Please see attached screenshot.

[image]

Here's how it works.

A is a slider that goes up and down, and the red line uses the centre point of the A slider to draw its start point.

B is another slider, but this goes left and right (stops in the middle as shown below).

The current issue is, the red line should always rest on top of B like a see-saw. Currently the line's end point has a fixed x position so it is always in line with the green crosses below to the right. But I need to position the end Y point of the line correctly so that the line as a whole is resting on top of B at all times. Whether the user slides A or B.

My guess is I need to work out some form of distance calculation with angles. I have something along the lines of:

Called 60fps:

```
this.startPoint.x = this.verticalSliderModel.xPos;
this.startPoint.y = this.verticalSliderModel.yPos;
this.endPoint.x = 653;
this.endPoint.y = this.horizontalSliderModel.yPos;

var angle = Phaser.Math.angleBetween(this.startPoint.x, this.startPoint.y, this.endPoint.x, this.endPoint.y);

this.seeSawController.updateModel(this.startPoint, this.endPoint, angle, width);
this.seeSawController.updateView();
```

I then use html canvas to draw the line:

```
update(start:Point, end:Point, angle:number, width:number) {

    this.bmd.clear();
    this.bmd.ctx.beginPath();
    this.bmd.ctx.moveTo(start.x, start.y);
    this.bmd.ctx.lineTo(end.x, end.y);
    this.bmd.ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    this.bmd.ctx.stroke();
    this.bmd.ctx.closePath();
    this.bmd.render();
}
```

So yeah I want to calculate the green cross plot points moving forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this with some basic trigonometry.

I wrote the code in Unity, but the general idea should be the same.

Consider the following image:

[image]

We already have P1 and P2.
Here is some code to calculate the rest with comments:

```
    //Get points P1 and P2 based on circles
    Vector2 p1 = A.transform.position;
    Vector2 p2 = B.transform.position + new Vector3 (0, B.Radius);

    //calculate P3 using defined area bounds
    float px = AreaRight.transform.position.x + AreaRight.transform.localScale.x;
    Vector2 p3 = new Vector2 (px, p1.y);

    //Calculate angle (a) between P1 and P2
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2 (p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x);

    //Caculate the distance (h) between P3 and P4
    float height = Mathf.Tan (angle) * (p3 - p1).magnitude;

    //Set the P4 point we are looking for
    Vector2 p4 = new Vector2 (p3.x, p3.y + height);

    //Draw the line
    Line.SetLine (A.transform.position, p4);
```

Bonus gif of demo:

[image]